# Can I control the USB port (on a Linux system) from another computer?

Tags: usb, share

I have a problem that might be a bit like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29207980/701410). I'm setting up my workshop and I have a Linux workstation (that might be replaced with an iMac in the future) on one side of my workshop. On the other side I have several devices that need to be controlled via USB connections. The problem is the distance is too long for a USB cable. I have tried USB-over-ethernet, but that won't work here. (It's in the 2nd floor of a barn, we have lightning issues there and have lost equipment due to surges, so the ethernet cables in that area are fiber - and the USB/ethernet converters won't work with fiber in between them.)

I'm thinking I can put a Raspberry Pi, running Linux, near where the devices will go and plug the USB cables into the Pi. That's where I'm stuck. Is there any way to share the USB devices over a LAN so my workstation can see them and treat them like local devices?

---

Edit: Since posting this, I have found [USB/IP](http://usbip.sourceforge.net/) and several developers who have created commercial products from the open source version. One of these claims Mac support, but there are still issues I'm trying to resolve. (For instance, they say their Linux server works on Ubuntu, but I want to use Raspbian, which is lighter weight. I don't know if I can use their server on Raspbian, or if I can use the open source USB/IP on the Pi and use their Mac version on my iMac.) When I get clear answers about this, I'll post it as an answer if it solves my problem.

Comment: I'd search for "USB over IP", but I haven't used technologies like that myself.

Comment: @DavidGrayson Thank you. I haven't had time to edit this. A big issue I was having was too much noise over signal in my searches. I get things like suggestions Samba, but that's for storage devices. (I have a post I've sent to the Samba mailing list about this - just in case.) But I have just recently found USB/IP and was going to edit the question to include that. The problem is it's limited to Linux and Windows and eventually I'll want to use a Mac as my work station.

Answer (score -2):

Power surges? You might want to bury another grounding rod on the opposite side of the building.

Try one of the power line ethernet devices?

Other than this, rs232 over ethernet or a wifi bridge - purchasing a low cost, used computer to reroute the signal might also be an option.

Comment: Hi, James, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer may work better as a comment than an answer. You do bring up something to deal with the surges, but it's not going to help. This wiring in on the 2nd floor, right near the outer wall, and we've lost equipment and in-wall CAT6 wiring before from lightning that hit near enough to create a charge in the wire. That never happened in my old house, 40 minutes away, but that was in the 'burbs, with power lines nearby. Out here I'm amazed at new precautions I've had to take because of the frequency of lightning.

Comment: So the bottom line for this area is going to have to be no data wiring in the walls or ceiling. I'm also not going over wifi for controlling any machine. While it generally works without issue, for a CNC, which could do a lot of damage in a few seconds if something goes wrong, I'm using a wired control line, which, in this case, means using fiber to go through the walls. I'm not clear what RS232 will do, since I'd still have to have a USB port on each end, unless you are thinking using RS232 converters on each end.

Comment: I'm not allowed to leave comments on other random responses due to reputation points. I have to start my own.

Comment: To clarify though. Have you tried adding a separate grounding rod system for building?

Comment: Rs323 is a medium voltage signal. I'm honestly stumped as to why you can run usb, and fiber, but not ethernet.

Comment: We have serious lightning issues here. I've had multiple pieces of equipment in that building blown out by nearby lightning strikes. In one place, it was likely from the current in the ground when it hit, but I have lost equipment from the ethernet lines run through the ceiling (about 18" below the roof) during storms from induction! I've had CAT6 cable blown out because it wasn't connected to anything at either end, but had been, and had been working, but, after a storm, couldn't handle any traffic. The tester failed it! (Cont'd)

Comment: Without going into details, the 1st floor is a different situation and once I replaced the ethernet cable that was near the ground with fiber optic and converters, stuff there stopped blowing out. For the 2nd floor, I've been replacing the ethernet with fiber optic cables. So I can run ethernet through the fiber without lightning blowing things out. As for USB, I can run a cable for TESTING, but not long term. BUT if I can do USB over IP, then that solves the issue. (I tried USB over ethernet with converters, but that won't work over fiber optic cables.)

Comment: Note I explained the lightning issues in the question, explained it again here for clarity, and still had to explain it a 3rd time. The point is not to start saying, "I can't see why you can't just do this." The point is to provide a clear answer to the question, which is how to do USB over IP. We never know what a person's situation is and, yes, maybe asking IN A COMMENT, "Would you be open to a solution on an RS232 cable?" would be okay, but continuing to try to push a point when the person asking has made it clear (three times now) that solution won't work, it becomes a waste of time.

Comment: Friend, what a load.   ...an isolated grounding system is one that parallels existing infrastructure. It is intended to handle induction.

Comment: I cannot add a proper comment here.  However a fiber to ethernet duplexer might be the solution to remote control. That is IF you go with remote pi. Otherwise, you would need a duplexer with and fpga tuned to usb protocol - OR, a chain linked solution, one way or another it will require a sort of duplexer.